# How to develop so that the fields below indicated are transformed into an MS WORD file, in an organized manner?

Tags: python, python-docx

Fields:

A.
Process number (with mask and
15 characters)

B.
Stick Name (must be selection button and list with
3 options)

C.
Part Name (must be text field of
free filling)

Comment: Your "organized manner" specification is way too broad.  Show your attempt and ask a more focused question.  And the last paragraph of your problem is senseless gibberish.  Is that supposed to be some kind of template?

Comment: @TomServo Sorry.It wasn't me that made that question.It was sent to me.

Comment: This is just an exercise.After i finish this they want me to create an executable file and sent them.

Comment: Do you think this is very complex to do?But answering your question i think they want a type of template

Comment: Just because it was sent to you doesn't make it a good question here.  Turn it into a good quality question. Read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Comment: Ok.I will change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not already have python-docx installed, run the following pip command to install it:

```
pip install python-docx
```

Create a new python file and import docx

```
import docx
```

You can now do something of the following:

```
MyDocument = docx.Document # Tells python the file extension to write to
MyDocument.add_heading("This is a heading.", 0) # Makes a heading. Replace '0' with 1 or 2 to make it smaller
MyDocument.add_paragraph("Hey, I'm a paragraph!") # Makes a paragraph
MyDocument.save("C:/WordDocumentTest.docx") # Saves the document to its respective name, replace C:/ with a directory path
```

This creates a paragraph under the .docx file extension, adds a sample paragraph, a heading, and saves it to the given name. You can add as many paragraphs as you want as long as it is given a handle, a paragraph to add, and a saving path.

You can also create a run to put a section under a given paragraph by giving it a handle:

```
secondParagraph = MyDocument.add_paragraph("I am the second paragraph!")
secondParagraph.add_run("This is a run added as a section of the second paragraph")
```

Here's my best answer to how to achieve what you want:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

MyDocument = docx.Document # Tells python the file extension to write to

MyDocument.add_heading('Process Number,', level=1)
MyDocument.add_paragraph('')
MyDocument.add_heading('Stick Name', level=1)
MyDocument.add_paragraph('List Option 1', style='List Number')
MyDocument.add_paragraph('List Option 2', style='List Number')
MyDocument.add_paragraph('List Option 3', style='List Number')

records = ((3, 'Sample'),(7, 'Sample'))

table = MyDocument.add_table(rows=1, cols=2)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Part Name'
hdr_cells[1].text = ' '
for name, id, desc in records:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = ''
    row_cells[1].text = ''

MyDocument.save("C:/WordDocumentTest.docx") # Saves the document to its respective name, replace C:/ with a directory path
```

If you need to look up something else, here's the [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)